# Scrapy items are not being properly yielded

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have 2 for loops in my spider, one for images and one for room data. They both work fine when run independently but when put them both in my spider depending on which one come first it will either correctly provide the image urls or the room data but not both. I have tried moving around the yields and I have read the documentation about running multiple spiders but I just want to know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code, I am very new to Scrapy and just learned about item loaders for formatting data so I haven't used any of that yet.

items.py

```
import scrapy

class ResortItem(scrapy.Item):

    # images
    images = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()

    # room details and amenities
    room_title = scrapy.Field()
    square_feet = scrapy.Field()
    kitchen = scrapy.Field()
    num_baths = scrapy.Field()
    max_guests = scrapy.Field()
    beds = scrapy.Field()
    washer_dryer = scrapy.Field()
    room_amenities = scrapy.Field()
```

scraper.py

```
import scrapy
from items import ResortItem

class ScraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scraper'
    allowed_domains = ['domains']
    start_urls = [
        'urls'
    ]
def parse(self, response):
        item = ResortItem()
            unit_img_path = units_img.xpath(unit_image_selector).getall()

            url_list = imgs_path + unit_img_path
            image_urls = [
                "url" + x for x in url_list]
            item['image_urls'] = image_urls
            yield item
            # gets and sets the room_title to an item
            room_title = units.xpath(room_nameSelector).get().strip()
            item['room_title'] = room_title
            beds = units.xpath(bedSelector).getall()
            item['beds'] = beds
            num_baths = units.xpath(bathsSelector).get().strip()
            item['num_baths'] = num_baths
            # gets the square feet and sets it to an item
            square_feet = units.xpath(sqftSelector).get().strip()
            item['square_feet'] = square_feet
            room_amenities = units.xpath(room_amenitiesSelector).getall()

            # Pulls Washer/Dryer amenity if available
            washer_amenity = 'Washer'
            washer_dryer = list(
                filter(lambda x: washer_amenity in x, room_amenities))

            # Extracts the washer/dryer room_amenities list
            # setting room_amenities item
            room_amenities = [
                x for x in room_amenities if not x.startswith('Washer')]
            item['room_amenities'] = room_amenities

            # formatting Kitchen data
            # setting kitchens item
            kitchen = units.xpath(kitchenSelector).get().strip()
            item['kitchen'] = kitchen

            yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move this

```
        unit_image_selector = './/div[@class = "orbit-wrapper"]/ul//li/figure/img//@src'
        unit_img_path = units_img.xpath(unit_image_selector).getall()

        url_list = imgs_path + unit_img_path
        image_urls = [
            "https://clubwyndham.wyndhamdestinations.com" + x for x in url_list]
        item['image_urls'] = image_urls
```

inside the second loop

```
unit = './/div[contains(@id, "unit-details")]'
for units in response.xpath(unit):
```

an remove the first loop and unnecessarily variables

Comment: wow, thank you sooo much! I have been staring at this problem for for 3 days and I didn't realize I had the same for loop. It works perfectly